# How do I encrypt a string with "PKCS#7-Standard and Base64 coded" in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, encryption, base64

I have to encrypt a string within an XML element with "PKCS#7-Standard and Base64 coded" and also decrypt it when I get the XML as a response.
I guess I will receive a public key for encryption.

But the more I read about it the more confused I get. 
I've also found a lot of code examples in Java and PHP, but I have to do it in Perl.

For the base64 encoding and decoding I have already found the module to do so
which works fine: MIME::Base64.

What I am curious about is that the paper says the security must follow these prerequisites:

- RSA-Algorithm with minimum 2048 Bit
- AES – Advanced Encryption Standard [RFC 3565] (256 Bit, CBC-Modus)
- SHA-256
- X.509 v3-certificate (V1.0.2)
- PKCS#7 – electronic signature and encryption

I am totally confused as I thought I just had to encrypt with a public key and sign with private key. I have problems in understanding the prerequisites.

Is the module Crypt::SMIME from CPAN the right one?
How could I simulate the situation by creating certificates/keys by myself for testing?